# useReducer ActionsType unable to make payload type-safe

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I am using react hook useReducer with typescript and I am unable to make it typesafe because whenever I try to give the action type with payload it returns error.

```
interface State {
  checkedEvents: string[];
  seriesIndex: number;
  listHeight: number;
  chart: Chart | undefined;
}

interface ComponentActions {
  type: 'setInitialOptions' | 'setCheckedEvents';
  payload: State | { checkedEvents: string[] };
}

function reducer(state: State, action: ComponentActions): State {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case 'setInitialOptions':
      return {
        chart: payload.chart,
        checkedEvents: payload.checkedEvents,
        seriesIndex: payload.seriesIndex,
        listHeight: payload.listHeight
      };
    case 'setCheckedEvents':
      return { ...state, checkedEvents: payload.checkedEvents };
    default:
      throw new Error();
}
```

This is what the type error looks like:
[image]

Any ideas why this happens and how to make payload type-safe?

Comment: What I am going to say is not related to your issue, but consider using redux-actions. According to my experience, that's the best way to describe reducers and to have good type definitions.

Comment: @DanielStoyanoff sorry, the title of this post must've been not informative. my issue is the inability to make the payload type-safe. Redux-actions might be a solution but I am looking for a way to do it without additional libraries (only with react utilities).

Comment: you might want to checkout https://github.com/Code-Y/redux-fluent

Answer (score 1):

declare interfaces for all actions
and use it in reducer

```
class Chart {
    some: string = "";
}

interface State {
    checkedEvents: string[];
    seriesIndex: number;
    listHeight: number;
    chart: Chart | undefined;
}

const SET_INITIAL_OPTIONS = "setInitialOptions";
type SET_INITIAL_OPTIONS = typeof SET_INITIAL_OPTIONS;
const SET_CHECKED_EVENTS = "setCheckedEvents";
type SET_CHECKED_EVENTS = typeof SET_CHECKED_EVENTS;

interface ISetInitialOptionsAction {
    type: SET_INITIAL_OPTIONS;
    payload: State;
}

interface ISetCheckedEventsAction {
    type: SET_CHECKED_EVENTS;
    payload: { checkedEvents: string[] };
}

type ComponentActions = ISetInitialOptionsAction | ISetCheckedEventsAction;

export default function reducer(state: State, action: ComponentActions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_INITIAL_OPTIONS:
            return {
                chart: action.payload.chart,
                checkedEvents: action.payload.checkedEvents,
                seriesIndex: action.payload.seriesIndex,
                listHeight: action.payload.listHeight
            };
        case SET_CHECKED_EVENTS:
            return {
                 ...state, 
                 checkedEvents: action.payload.checkedEvents
            };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
"typescript": "^3.3.1"
```

Build successful. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: This will force him always specify all fields. In case of the second reducer, the payload will need to include the whole State, which is not the desired effect in my opinion.

Comment: @Daniel Stoyanoff Well, you are right. And I rewrote the answer. I use this approach in my projects

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev Thanks, but the issue persists. Still says `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'State | { checkedEvents: string[]; }'.
  Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ checkedEvents: string[]; }'.`

Comment: Please, check again

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev I've tried with the updated answer, still error.